# Javascript stops working on entering multiple class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a simple problem here with JavaScript. I have this JS code which I use to highlight rows in a price table. The issue is that if I used multiple class names at a time it stops working. For example:

`<div class="el1 someclass">Hover does not work in this</div>`

`<div class="el1">Hover does work in this</div>`

The JS:

```
var classes = ["el1", "el2", "el3", "el4", "el5", "el6", "el7", "el8", "el9","el10","el11","el12", "el13","el14","el15","el16","el17","el18","el19","el20","el21","el22", "el23", "el24","el25" ]; //list of your classes
var elms = {};
var n = {}, nclasses = classes.length;
function changeColor(classname, color) {
    var curN = n[classname];
    for(var i = 0; i < curN; i ++) {
        elms[classname][i].style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}
for(var k = 0; k < nclasses; k ++) {
    var curClass = classes[k];
    elms[curClass] = document.getElementsByClassName(curClass);
    n[curClass] = elms[curClass].length;
    var curN = n[curClass];
    for(var i = 0; i < curN; i ++) {
        elms[curClass][i].onmouseover = function() {
            changeColor(this.className, "#dbdbdb");
        };
        elms[curClass][i].onmouseout = function() {
            changeColor(this.className, "transparent");
        };
    }
};
```

Can somebody help me out please, I'm a newbie in JS.

Thanks ..

Comment: @Fahad do you need something like this?http://jsbin.com/gareyemada/1/edit?html,js

Comment: Is there any other approach to this? If don't use classes, can I use ids?

Comment: no classes would be fine I think the problem is with your `changecolor` only

Comment: @Justcode I tried implementing you code, its now only selecting the first element of every row, not the whole row ..

Comment: you need whole row? you should mention it early And btw where's the whole row?

Comment: plz see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c2zrkxd1/)..i think this is what you want..

Comment: @Justcode Here the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9e1d693j

Comment: @FahadSohail I think *Kartikeya* has a right suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `className` property on a dom element returns the complete className; that is, if some element has multiple classes (e.g. `<div class="herp derp"></div>`), then `className = "herp derp"`.

If you want to call `changeColor` on each of these multiple classes, try something like this:

```
// first, change the order of the arguments on the changeColor function so we can pre-apply the color argument
function changeColor(color, classname) {
    var curN = n[classname];
    for(var i = 0; i < curN; i ++) {
        elms[classname][i].style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}
```

Now, we can change how we call changeColor

```
// now, where you previously called changeColor, do something like this
this.className.split(" ").forEach(changeColor.bind(null, "transparent"));
// we now will call changeColor on all of the classes of this with the appropriate color ("transparent" or "#dbdbdb")
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var classes = ["el1", "el2", "el3", "el4", "el5", "el6", "el7", "el8", "el9","el10","el11","el12", "el13","el14","el15","el16","el17","el18","el19","el20","el21","el22", "el23", "el24","el25" ]; //list of your classes
var elms = {};
var n = {}, nclasses = classes.length;
function changeColor(classname, color) {
    var curN = n[classname];
    for(var i = 0; i < curN; i ++) {
        elms[classname][i].style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}
for(var k = 0; k < nclasses; k ++) {
    var curClass = classes[k];
    elms[curClass] = document.getElementsByClassName(curClass);
    n[curClass] = elms[curClass].length;
    var curN = n[curClass];
    for(var i = 0; i < curN; i ++) {
        elms[curClass][i].onmouseover = function() {
            changeColor(this.className.split(' ')[0], "#dbdbdb");
        };
        elms[curClass][i].onmouseout = function() {
            changeColor(this.className.split(' ')[0], "transparent");
        };
    }
};
```

```html
<div class="el1 someclass">Hover does not work in this</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="el1">Hover does work in this</div>
```

The problem was with the

```
function changeColor(classname, color) {
    var curN = n[classname];
    for(var i = 0; i < curN; i ++) {
        elms[classname][i].style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}
```

Here you're assigning hover to each element where this reference would

```
>>            changeColor(this, "#dbdbdb");
```

pass the only one element and will change the color

Comment: I already tried implementing this, the code now only selects the first element of row, not the whole row ..

Comment: Change to split(' ')[0]

Comment: @FahadSohail *kartikeyan* is the real here

Answer (score 0):

Check out the fiddle I created. The problem is when you are trying to change color you are again passing in the class name and trying to select the element again while you already have the reference to the element where you are changing the background color. So pass on the element directly and change the background.

http://jsfiddle.net/5eLhsqxv/

`

```
var n = {}, nclasses = classes.length;
function changeColor(elm, color) {
        elm.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
for(var k = 0; k < nclasses; k ++) {
    var curClass = classes[k];
    elms[curClass] = document.getElementsByClassName(curClass);
    console.log(elms[curClass]);
    console.log(curClass);
    n[curClass] = elms[curClass].length;
    var curN = n[curClass];
    for(var i = 0; i < curN; i ++) {
        console.log(elms[curClass][i]);
        elms[curClass][i].onmouseover = function() {
            changeColor(this, "#dbdbdb");
        };
        elms[curClass][i].onmouseout = function() {
            changeColor(this, "transparent");
        };
    }
};
```

`